# how to set hadoop I map tasks maximum simultaneously in one server

Tags: mapreduce

I used the parameter `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=2` to control that only two mappers are running in one node at the same time. But after I set it, it didn't take effect, I could see there are 19 mappers were running at the same time in one node.
So is there any other parameter has overrided that one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to control the number of concurrent map tasks to be 2,
you can add the following properties to mapped-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.running.map.limit</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
```